# VBA code to highlight the cell which do not contain specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of below values in A column as below. I want to highlight the cells which do not have the strings "Yes", "No", and "N/A"

```
Moderate
High
Yes - no structural changes
High
Moderate
Yes
Moderate
N/A
High
No
Nos
```

I have tried the below VBA but it is also not highlighting the values like "Yes - no structural changes" and "Nos".

```
Dim a As Range
For Each a In Range(Range("a1"), Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not (a.Value Like "**Yes**" Or a.Value Like "**No**" Or a.Value Like "**N/A**") Then
        a.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: Your narrative seems to contradict itself. Do you want to highlight the cells that **are not** Yes, No, N/A so strings like ***Nos*** would not be highlighted or do you want them highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a conditional formatting rule.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
  with .range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
    with .formatconditions.add(type:=xlexpression, _
                               formula1:="=OR(COUNTIF(A1, ""*yes*""), COUNTIF(A1, ""*no*""), COUNTIF(A1, ""*n/a*""))")
      .interior.color = vbred
    end with
  end with
end with
```

Your own code needs to use wildcard characters with Like.

```
If Not (a.Value Like "*Yes*" Or a.Value Like "*No*" Or a.Value Like "*N/A*") Then
```